# How to get a file Variables in Batch-File

Tags: batch-file, variables, command

Let's imagine a Batch game saves your progress in a file.bat file, when we edit that file we got :

```
set Health=100
set Sword=Gold
```

i used this command in a Batch file but it's didn't work :

```
for /f "eol=- delims=" %%a in (file.bat) do set "%%a"
echo Your health is %Health%
echo Your sword is made of %Sword%
```

it leave it blank.

but if i maked a file like the above but removed the `set` (only Health=100 and Sword=Gold without set), it works and give me the variable Health and Sword, but when the `set` command added it didn't work, if any one knows solution please tell me and Thanks !

**I want a command that give me the Variables i don't want to just delete the `set` command from the file, because if i did that the game that saved the bat file will get corrupted while extracting the Variables from the file to continue where you left the game.**

Comment: if the set command is in the file, you are literally doing `set "set Health=100"` , simply put `) do %%a`

Comment: So i will change the command to this ? `for /f "eol=- delims=" %%a in (file.bat) do "%%a"`

Comment: I would only use `%%a` without quotes.

Comment: Thank You so much @LotPings you really helped me :)

Answer (score 0):

Tip for game-generation:

If you reserve a character as a prefix for variables-you-want-to-save (eg all variables I want to save/reload start with `#`) then all you need to *save* a game is

```
set #>"mygamefile.txt"
```

and all you need to *reload* a game is

```
for /f "usebackqdelims=" %%a in ("mygamefile.txt") do set "%%a"
```

To zap all `#` variables (useful before reloading a game) use

```
for /f "delims==" %%a in ('set # 2^>nul') do set "%%a="
```

Comment: remove the `set ` in `") do set "%%a"`. As an alternative you could `(echo @echo off & set #)>"mygamefile.bat"` and to reload simply: `call "mygamefile.bat"`

Comment: @stephan Please explain your reasoning. The code works perfectly as posted.

Comment: the textfile contains lines like `set Health=100` (see comments to the question). You add another `set`.

Comment: @Stephan OP's method is overly complex. The method I suggest replaces that method.

Comment: I agree, but OP explicitely said ` i don't want to just delete the set command from the file`