# How would I make the batch file give a menu at any time by pressing "q", without having to write it over and over again throughout?

Tags: batch-file

I have a game screen of an RPG I am creating:

```
:OBJ1
CLS
echo.
echo.   
echo The tiger rolls down the steep hill...
echo What do you do?
echo.
echo.
CHOICE /c abc /n /m ">"
IF %errorlevel%==1 (GOTO ATTACK)
IF %errorlevel%==2 (GOTO WALK)
IF %errorlevel%==3 (GOTO COLLECT)
```

As you can tell, once you select a choice, it goes to another screen. After that screen, you select another choice. And another. I have many of those similar bits of code, each with different situations. I was wondering instead of adding a choice "q" for pause for *each situation*, if there was a way to have a global detection of when the letter "q" is pressed.

So that no matter the screen, if you press "q", it instantly goes to a pause menu.

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: I'm a little confused by your provided code, it waits at the prompt for a single character input, yet never gives the end user any idea of which of the only three characters in the available character set are acceptable entries!

Comment: Sorry, I should have included a "press a for attack, b for walk, ect" text.

Comment: Short answer, you have to have a 4th option for your choice commands.

Comment: Yes, I know, but I don't want to do that for *every* text of code like above. Its like an RPG with different choices, and I want to have a pause menu without having to put the code in *every* time. Sorry if I'm being vague here

Comment: So you know what the answer is but you don't want to accept it as the way it has to be done?  This is kind of like trying to put a square peg in a round hole.  Good luck with that.

Comment: I mean, I know *one* way of doing it. I just wanted to know if there was a more *efficient* way of doing it, instead of writing it out each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a little demo:

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL
SET Posx=15
SET Posy=15
SET Posz=0
CALL :choose awc "ATTACK:Attack" "WALK:Walk" "COLLECT:Collect"
ECHO Jump to %jumpto% as choice made was %choicemade%
CALL :choose eds "EAT:Eat Ration" "DRINK:Drink Potion" "SLEEP:Sleep"
ECHO Jump to %jumpto% as choice made was %choicemade%
CALL :choose news "NORTH:Go North" "EAST:Go East" "SOUTH:Go South" "WEST:Go West"
ECHO Jump to %jumpto% as choice made was %choicemade%
ECHO ---------------------------------------------------
CALL :choose news "GO 0 1:Go North" "GO 1 0:Go East" "GO -1 0:Go West" "GO 0 -1:Go South"
ECHO CALL :%jumpto% as choice made was %choicemade%
CALL :%jumpto%
CALL :choose news "GO 0 1:Go North" "GO 1 0:Go East" "GO -1 0:Go West" "GO 0 -1:Go South"
ECHO CALL :%jumpto% as choice made was %choicemade%
CALL :%jumpto%
CALL :choose newsd "GO 0 1:Go North" "GO 1 0:Go East" "GO -1 0:Go West" "GO 0 -1:Go South" "GO 0 0 1:Down Stairs"
ECHO CALL :%jumpto% as choice made was %choicemade%
CALL :%jumpto%

GOTO :EOF

:: Move in a direction
:GO
ECHO Current position: %posx% %posy% AT level %posz%
SET /a posx+=%1
SET /a posy+=%2
SET /a posz+=%3+0
ECHO Current position: %posx% %posy% AT level %posz%
:: set ERRORLEVEL to 0
CD .
CALL :enc_%posx%_%posy%_%posz% 2>nul

GOTO :eof

:: Encounter at 16,14,1
:enc_16_14_1
ECHO it's dark
GOTO :eof

:choose
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
SET "params=%*"
SET "choices=q%1qx"

:chooseloop
SET /a choicemade=0
FOR %%Z IN (%params% " :Pause" "ENDGAME:Exit Game") DO (
 FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%X IN ("%%~Z") DO (
  IF !choicemade! neq 0 (
   CALL ECHO %%choices:~!choicemade!,1%% %%Y
   SET "jumpto!choicemade!=%%X"
  )
  SET /a choicemade +=1
 )
)
choice /c %choices:~1% /n /m ">"
SET "jumpto=!jumpto%errorlevel%!"
SET "choicemade=!choices:~%errorlevel%,1!"
IF NOT "%choicemade%"=="q"  GOTO exitchoose
:: pause code

PAUSE

GOTO chooseloop

:exitchoose
endlocal&SET "jumpto=%jumpto%"&SET "choicemade=%choicemade%"
GOTO :eof
```

I can't see why you would need a `pause` function. batch will pause until you operate the key in any case.

The `:choose` subroutine takes `n` parameters. The first is the list of valid keys (q and x are added by the routine) and the remainder are `"destination-data: prompt-text"` in the order that the valid-keys are specified.

The variable `choices` is set to the choices specified, plus `q` and `x` at the end (as these always operate) plus an extra `q` at the beginning. I put this extra character in because batch-substringing counts from "character 0" whereas the `errorlevel` established by `choice` counts from `1`.

`:chooseloop` echoes a 1-characters substring from `choices` depending on `choicemade` which is simply a counter. We don't want to show the first parameter in `params`, so starting at `choicemade=1`, show the one-character string starting at the `choicemade`th character, and the menu-text, then set `jumpto1`..`jumpton` to the destination-data.

Make a choice, setting `errorlevel`.

Use `errorlevel` to set `jumpto` to the destination-data in `jumpto1`..`jumpton` as appropriate, and set `choicemade` to the actual choice-letter.

Now, if the choice-letter is not `q`, we need to return to the caller, but if it *is* `q` we execute a pause, and return to `:chooseloop` to repeat the menu-generation and `choice` entry.

If the choice-character is not `q`, we simply terminate the local environment and set `jumpto` and `choicemade` ready for the main routine.

If you run the demo, you'll find `jumpto` contains the destination data. You *could* use this directly, or you can be a little sneaky.

Notice that on the 4th demo onwards, `CALL :%jumpto%` is executed. The `:GO` routine accepts the two parameters (optionally 3) to move x,y[,z] on the map.

The `:GO` routine simply adds the first parameter to `posx` and the second to `posy`. The third parameter may or may not exist, so `0` is added in order that the syntax for `set /a` is satisfied. I've reported before and after x,y,z positions.

Now having moved, we set `errorlevel` to `0` using `cd .` and then attempt to call `:enc_%posx%_%posy%_%posz%` That is, an internal subroutine called `enc_thecubeyouarelocatedin`. This may or may not exist. If it exists, it'll be executed. If not, `cmd` will simply issue an error message that can be suppressed by the `2>nul` and set `errorlevel` to `1`. Note that `goto nonexistenetlabel` would exit the program and generate a nasty message.

In this way, specials for particular locations can be processed, but in the end it will all return to the original location that executed the `call :GO...`

And if you're looking for a way to load/save the game, try here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50639536/2128947